# not getting proper data which is fetched from csv file

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

i have csv file having two field image name and email like below

```
img/img (1), a@gmail.com
```

I am trying to show this data on image popup (lightbox) as a caption of that image. I first tried by applying on first image from the group of images as below. But its showing output like `Array Array` instead of `img/img (1) a@gmail.com`.

```
 <ul id="itemContainer">
   <?php
    $file_handle = fopen("imggallery.csv", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $lines_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    foreach ( $lines_of_text as $line_of_text): ?>

        <li><a href="img/img (1).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $lines_of_text[0].$lines_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (1).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>

   <?php endforeach; ?>     

                    <li><a href="img/img (2).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="My caption"><img src="img/img (2).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="img/img (3).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery"><img src="img/img (3).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="img/img (4).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery"><img src="img/img (4).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="img/img (5).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery"><img src="img/img (5).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="img/img (6).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery"><img src="img/img (6).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="img/img (7).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery"><img src="img/img (7).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="img/img (8).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery"><img src="img/img (8).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="img/img (9).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery"><img src="img/img (9).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="img/img (10).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery"><img src="img/img (10).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>

 </ul>
```

Anyone have idea how should do that?

**Edit:** Images are getting repeated by following code:

```
 <ul id="itemContainer">
 <?php

$file_handle = fopen("imggallery.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {

$lines_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
foreach ( $lines_of_text as $line_of_text): ?>
                <li><a href="img/img (1).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (1).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/img (2).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (2).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                 <li><a href="img/img (3).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (3).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/img (4).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (4).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/img (5).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (5).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/img (6).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (6).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/img (7).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (7).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/img (8).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (8).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/img (9).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (9).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/img (10).jpg" data-lightbox="imggallery" data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>"><img src="img/img (10).jpg" alt="image"></a></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>                  

      </ul>
```

Updated csv file like below:

```
img/img (1),a@gmail.com
img/img (2),b@gmail.com
img/img (3),c@gmail.com
img/img (4),d@gmail.com
img/img (5),e@gmail.com
img/img (6),f@gmail.com
img/img (7),g@gmail.com
img/img (8),h@gmail.com
img/img (9),i@gmail.com
img/img (10),j@gmail.com
```

Comment: var_dump($line_of_text); before using it. What does it print?

Comment: @ user4035: Can you please tell me how do I check that ? As new to this csv functions.

Comment: foreach ( $lines_of_text as $line_of_text): var_dump($line_of_text);?>

Comment: @novice you just need to add the line `var_dump($lines_of_text)` into your code to see what is really being stored in that variable. Beyond that, you should have a look at function `str_getcsv` as well. Here is an example from   http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv')); This will take your entire CSV file and parse it into an array.

Comment: @ user4035 :`array (size=2)
  0 => string 'img/img (1)' (length=11)
  1 => string 'a@gmail.com' (length=11)` result is like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
data-title="<?php print $lines_of_text[0].$lines_of_text[1];?>
```

Use this:

```
data-title="<?php print $line_of_text[0].$line_of_text[1];?>
```

Not "lines" but *"line"*. "$lines_of_text" is a 2 dimensional array, containing all the lines, read from csv. You need to traverse it line by line.

### Update

You must output only 1 image inside the loop:

```
foreach ( $lines_of_text as $line_of_text): 
      $withoutExt = preg_replace('/.*\\/(.*)\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '$1', $line_of_text[0]);
?>
       <li>
           <a href="<?php print $line_of_text[0]; ?>" data-lightbox="imggallery" 
           data-title="<?php print $withoutExt.$line_of_text[1];?>">
               <img src="<?php print $line_of_text[0]; ?>" alt="image">
           </a>
        </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: ohh yes. now the data is displaying proper. but showing three images.

Comment: @novice How many images do you have in your csv file? What is incorrect?

Comment: @ user4035: I have updated the csv file with 10 images and email. Also updated the code as above. but images are getting repeated and can you please tell me how foreach loop should be, to get different caption?

Comment: @novice Look at update. Where do you want the captions? data-title attribute?

Comment: @ user4035 : yes. you are getting it right. To follow your Update code, should I have `img/img (1).jpg` etc stored in my csv file? because right now the `src` is like `img/img (1)` so image is not getting displayed. then the caption of image will be like this `img/img (1).jpg a@gmail.com`

Comment: @novice Yes, you should have the full name of the image in your csv.

Comment: @novice For the caption you can remove the extension of the file. Look at the updated code.

Comment: @ user4035 : that's awesome. can we get only image name of the image removing its path and extention like this `img (1) a@gmail.com`? As I have to store the full path of image in csv file now.

Answer (score 1):

You have made one careless mistake while using the variable name.

`$lines_of_text` - array of variable, 
`$line_of_text` - single value from array of `$lines_of_text` variable

But inside the loop of `$lines_of_text` variable you have used the same array variable instead `$line_of_text` for data-title